# POP!_OS Upgrade package removed higher resolution options from display settings

Tags: linux, drivers, intel-graphics, pop-os

I switched on my desktop today and was greeted by an ugly low resolution display. Checking the settings, there are now only 2 options available: 1024 x 768 or 800 x 600.

There were previously around 20 options and I was using 1920 x something.

I'm running POP!OS 20.04 LTS

I checked /var/log/apt/history.log and found the following:

```
Start-Date: 2021-03-28  09:43:04
Commandline: apt-get --allow-downgrades -y install pop-upgrade libpop-upgrade-gtk
Upgrade: libpop-upgrade-gtk:amd64 (0.1.1~1608137131~20.04~d3bfb98, 0.1.1~1616430952~20.04~7df32bb), pop-upgrade:amd64 (0.1.1~1608137131~20.04~d3bfb98, 0.1.1~1616430952~20.04~7df32bb)
End-Date: 2021-03-28  09:43:08
```

I've tried `$ sudo apt-get --allow-downgrades --reinstall install pop-upgrade libpop-upgrade-gtk` and rebooted, but it hasn't helped.

I also did:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update -m
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove --purge --remove --purge
```

**Diagnostic info:**

Output of `$ uname -a`

```
Linux pop-os 5.8.0-7642-generic #47~1614007149~20.04~82fb226-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 02:56:27 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `$ sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output of `$ sudo lspci -nn | grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9bc8] (rev 03)
```

In `/var/log/gpu-manager.log`

```
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.8.0-7642-generic/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.8.0-7642-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:9bc8
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card0-DP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
Single card detected
Nothing to do
```

Output of `sudo systemctl status gdm`

```
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enab>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-28 13:15:49 PST; 21min ago
    Process: 913 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status>
    Process: 926 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wait-for-drm (code=exited, status>
   Main PID: 927 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 9267)
     Memory: 10.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─927 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Mar 28 13:15:49 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Mar 28 13:15:49 pop-os systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Mar 28 13:15:50 pop-os gdm-launch-environment][939]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environm>
Mar 28 13:20:28 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't>
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't>
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon cont>
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try late>
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): sessi>
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started>
dad@pop-os:~$ sudo systemctl status gdm
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-28 13:15:49 PST; 22min ago
    Process: 913 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 926 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wait-for-drm (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 927 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 9267)
     Memory: 10.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─927 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Mar 28 13:15:49 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Mar 28 13:15:49 pop-os systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Mar 28 13:15:50 pop-os gdm-launch-environment][939]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): sessi>
Mar 28 13:20:28 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securett>
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securett>
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user >
Mar 28 13:20:42 pop-os gdm-password][1370]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unloc>
lines 1-20/20 (END)
```

I'm out of ideas. Any assistance, much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to "derpmatt" over on [chat.pop-os.org](https://chat.pop-os.org/) who pointed me to [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075157/unable-to-set-my-screen-resolution-higher/1075168) I now have it resolved for my login. However, I still am looking for a way to correct other users logins (without logging in as each) and also to correct the login screen which still looks like the login for a four year old!

I have tried copying my `~/.config/monitors.xml` file to `/var/lib/gdm3/.config` and changing the owner to `gdm` as recommended in numerous other posts, but this does not have any effect on my machine.

Thanks in advance.